# trouble with gitignore

Tags: git

With this `.gitignore` I expect that *.log files under directory `test` will not be included in any git transactions

```
:> cat ~/test/.gitignore
*/*/*.log
*/*/*__pycache__*
*/*/*out
```

However I have this conversation which suggests my gitignore is not defined to do what I expect.

Where is my error? Am I misinterpreting the conversation or is my .gitignore incorrect for what I expect.

```
:> git add .
===
:> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
===
Changes to be committed:
(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   ftp.log
===
:> git restore --staged ftp.log 
===
:> git status
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ftp.log
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to exclude the directory `test` you can add a new .gitignore to the `test` directory with the following:

```
*.log
```

You can also replace what you have in your current `.gitignore`:

```
*/*/*.log
```

with

```
**/*.log
```

to remove tracking from all `.log` files in directories of the project.

Comment: Yes. I had the `**/*.log` wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Try `**/*.log`

> A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

Answer (score 0):

Familiarise yourself with https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

> An asterisk "*" matches anything except a slash.

It looks like you want `*.log` instead of `*/*/*/...`; it will wildcard match all .log files in all subdirectories.

.gitignore matches files in reference to the repo's root directory, both hard references (`/foo/bar`) and soft references (`foo/bar`).